# searchlogic and virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Let's say I have the following model:

```
Person <AR
 def name
  [self.first_name,self.middle_name,self.last_name].select{|n| n.present?}.join(' ')
 end
end
```

How could I do a search on the virtual attribute with searchlogic, something like:

```
Person.search.name_like 'foo'
```

Of courese I could construct a large statement like:

```
Person.search.first_name_like_or_last_name_like_or_... 'argh'
```

but surely there is a more elegant way.

Comment: What is the SQL that should be built by the Searchlogic method?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good with SQL. Never needed to be thanks to RoR and the plugin searchlogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searchlogic can be combined with existing named scopes and must be in case of virtual attributes. One such would be:

```
 named_scope :name_like, lambda { |name| { :conditions => ['first_name LIKE  ? OR last_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%","%#{name}%","%#{name}%"] }}
```