# Traversing the models with meta_search and referring to the virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, meta-search

I'm trying to apply the meta_search to a form where among all the attributes the one is a search by the author's name. It's stored as the two attributes "first_name" and the "last_name" in the table authors.
I've created the following virtual attribute in the Author model:

```
  search_methods :name

  def name 
    self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
  end
```

The Authors and the Books model, which is the one I'm searching in, are associated like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
..

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
..
```

Now when I'm trying to paste the following input in the view I get the error:

```
<%= f.text_field :authors_name_contains, :placeholder => "author.." %>
```

But it works if I apply the conditions to the attributes "first_name" and "last_name" through the "or" operator here in the view.

What am I doing wrong? How to make the meta_search use the method "name"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.  If I understand meta_search correctly, it's looking at attributes generated by ActiveRecord (or whatever your back end is) so it wouldn't know anything about your virtual attributes.

Comment: As far as it's stated in the docs it looks like this is possible with the use of the scopes: https://github.com/dogenpunk/meta_search
However I can't make it work. Usage of the scopes was also suggested here (for the searchlogic though):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801096/searchlogic-and-virtual-attributes

Comment: I'm currently using this: `<%= f.search_field :authors_first_name_or_authors_last_name_contains, :placeholder => "author.." %>
while it seems to bulky to have in the view.

Comment: Maybe you need to create a scope on your model named authors_name_contains?