# searchlogic - searching for attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I have a table `symbols` which contains columns: `id and symbol_name`, where `id` is the primary key of that table

In my Symbol model, I have

```
class Symbol < ActiveRecord::Base

def symbol_id
"EMI:#{self.id}"
end

end
```

On my index.html.erb page, users can search for symbols with id 777 by entering "EMI:777" in the search textfield.

I am using searchlogic for searching.

```
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
    Search:
    <%= f.text_field :symbol_id_or_symbol_name_like %>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

When i use 'symbol_id' in the search form , i get the following error message:

```
The condition 'symbol_id' is not a valid condition, we could not find any scopes that match this.
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801096/searchlogic-and-virtual-attributes) it looks like you will want to do a [scope](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html) based on the virtual attribute:

```
class Symbol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :symbol_id
  scope :symbol_id_search, where("symbol_id = ?", symbol_id)  

  def initialize
    @symbol_id = "EMI:#{self.id}"
  end

end
```

I not sure that the `scope` is correct so you may need to dig into that a bit based on your model, controller, etc.